# Unable to locate package openal-soft

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, libraries

I'm trying to install `openal-soft` on Ubuntu Focal, but without luck.

This is the package I would like to install:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/openal-soft

**What I tried:**

```
sudo apt update
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt install openal-soft
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to install *binary* package using name of its [*source*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/openal-soft) package. They are different things. Source package has *openal-soft* name, during its compilation the following binary packages are produced:

> - `libopenal-data` – Software implementation of the OpenAL audio API (data files)
> - `libopenal-dev` – Software implementation of the OpenAL audio API (development files)
> - `libopenal1` – Software implementation of the OpenAL audio API (shared library)
> - `makehrtf` – HRTF Processing and Composition Utility
> - `openal-info` – Informational utility for the OpenAL audio API

So reproducible way to install binary packages of OpenAL is the following:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libopenal-dev makehrtf openal-info
```

and then you can start developing software using this library.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it is not the package for https://openal-soft.org/, but instead the source code for https://openal.org/?

Comment: Or is it the other way around? `openal-soft` is the source package for `openal-soft` and libopenal-dev is the compiled library of `openal-soft`?

Comment: This is how software debian packaging works. I do not know do you need to compile something or not. Please clarify your use case.

Comment: Yes, I would like to include the https://openal-soft.org/ library in my application using `CMake`

Comment: Then `openal.pc` for `pkg-config` [is contained](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libopenal-dev/filelist) in `libopenal-dev` . So it should normally be compiled.

Comment: Alright, I have no idea what a `*.pc` file does, but I guess I start to understand that I need that package in order to link against `openal`?

Comment: Yes, right. All `*-dev` packages are created for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to N0rbert's answer, I managed to install the package using:

`vcpkg install openal-soft`

This required `vcpkg` to be installed first:

https://lindevs.com/install-vcpkg-on-ubuntu/